# PySDL2 Bitmap Font

Tags: python, graphics, fonts, sdl, pysdl2

I'm currently trying to make a bitmap font for PySDL2 and am having an issue with the spacing between characters. The API requires a surface, universal character-glyph width & height, and character mapping. The font is created by reading a glyph from the bitmap of the specified width & height by correlating it to the mapping that is inputted.

```py
bmpfont = sdl2.ext.BitmapFont(font_surface, (64, 64), mapping)
```

I know a lot of game development frameworks utilize a similar pattern but allow for an XML list to account for the different sized characters (e.g., a 'w' is short & fat, where a '|' is tall & thin) by providing specific glyph width, heights, and offsets inside the bitmap. The PySDL2 BitmapFont [documentation](https://pysdl2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/sdl2ext_font.html) shows an offset dictionary, but to my knowledge (through several iterations of attempts) that's not able to be manipulated to accomplish a similar goal.

As you can see in my example below with '|'s and 'j's, the spacing looks silly because every single character is read as 64x64 pixels, and because of the aforementioned, I'm not able to control that spacing.

[image: pipes and jays]

Due to the project requirements that this is meant to be integrated into, it must be a bitmap font and I can't leverage something like the TTF library for PySDL2. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is supported by pysdl2, I only see constant width in its code. But the code of `sdl2.ext.BitmapFont` is not huge, you can look it up and implement minimal functionality by taking manual list of character widths or even by scanning image for black/transparent columns and counting that as an end of character glyph.

Comment: In general, how would u go about accomplishing that? @keltar

Comment: I think I'd have started with copying code of said python class and modifying its render method so it uses width from offsets table (check if library license allows that). Render function is small and easy to read, so it should not be very hard to do (right now it uses constant width). For test purposes I'd use manually filled offsets table with few glyphs being narrower - just to test rendering works as intended. Then there is a question on where to get offsets table - could be done manually, could be pre-calculated by separate tool beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using `py-sdl2`'s `ext.font` library, but generally the way to do this manually is to find the glyph, find its edges, and copy each one based on its individual bounding box. There's a guide here that describes this process in full using C++ and SDL2: https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/41_bitmap_fonts/index.php.